# Is it better to rewrite the on-hold questions into two separated questions? (By ourselves)

Tags: feature-request, questions

Whereas many questions are going to be on-hold by the moderator(s) (such as: [did-prophet-muhammad-die-naturally-or-was-he-killed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5945/did-prophet-muhammad-die-naturally-or-was-he-killed)), meanwhile, whereas there have done plenty of attempts for providing the answers (e.g. there are four answers for the above-mentioned question), therefore, would it be better if we divide the question(s) into two separated (view) questions (or edit it appropriately) in order to avoid argument?

(By paying attention to: [user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/))

As the moderator said “this is clearly opinion-based and just going to attract argument and debate rather than practical answers”
I remarked it because there are some users who are not online since a long time ago, then they probably won’t be online to look at the On-Hold alarm to edit their questions in order to prevent deleting their questions (by paying heed that plenty of times have wasted for proving the nice questions and answers)

So, would it be more profitable if we ourselves edit them appropriately in order to open those (profitable) questions?

Comment: This is a good example of a question closed by a moderator that shouldn't. I don't see any way you can re-write that question to make it any different. How can you make that question into 4? This is a good example of lack of a moderator for the moderators themselves.